# How to customize the path to generate and download a Swagger JSON file nestjs

Tags: swagger, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I have to change the path of the swagger json file, in nestjs documentation it is http://localhost:3000/api-json but for the standard have to keep it

http://localhost:3000/api/openapi.json

Let me know if there is any possible solution for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since v6.2 of `@nestjs/swagger` you can change that value using the `jsonDocumentUrl`/`yamlDocumentUrl` option like so:

```
SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document, {
  jsonDocumentUrl: 'openapi.json'
});
```